# Laravel 5 Dynamic Routes

Tags: c#, php, laravel-5, routes

I am coming from a C# .NET background, is it possible to setup dynamic routes in Laravel 5 like I can in C# MVC?

In my C# app I am using attribute routing so I do not have to manually declare each individual route-controller binding.

Just curious if I can do something similar in Laravel 5 with PHP7?

Comment: Yes, have you checked the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when you set a route such as the following:

```
Route::get('orders/{orders}', 'OrdersController@getStock');
```

You will be able to bind {orders} to a specific model?

If so, all you need to do, is open your RouteServiceProvider.php, and in the boot method, add the logic as you like, for example:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->bind('orders', function ($id)
    {
        return Order::findOrFail($id);
    });
}
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is the ability to something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 . By using attribute routing, I do not have to have a routes file with all my routes declared. Therefore, if the controller and method exist, then the route will exist as well. No need for a bulky routes file.

Comment: And there is much less maintenance with having not to create a route every time you create a controller/action pair.

Comment: Well, I don't know that kind of binding, but I think it is way better to have all routes declared in the routes file. It offers much more flexibility, allows to hide method names - I think it is just matter of time till you would prefer that kind of routing :)